# Unity scale does not work with a model imported from 3DSMAX

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

i can try to scale object with this scrip and it work if i use cube in unity but if i use a object import from 3DSMAX the object disappear from the scene, 
what could be the problem?

```
 void Update()
 {
   ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

   if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
   {
     Debug.Log(" you clicked on " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);

      if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "CONNECT")
      {
      // anim.Play("esplodi");
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("connect").transform.localScale += new Vector3(scalingspeed, scalingspeed, scalingspeed);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: what value do u have for `scalingspeed`? What are you import settings?

Comment: scalingspeed is = 0.. When i export from 3dsmax i set unity in meters.